# Fresco DraweeHolder and custom view

Tags: android, imageview, android-custom-view, fresco

Could anyone point me to an example which uses drawee holder to manage their custom image view. I am looking to create  a custom view which is something like the third thumbnail shown in the image here:

[Image URL](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/SJ80g0I_5i6Zw8OENwFL8zLdqjNhMbLL5_XqziPDj8ygZdRFQNkCl5s1K0Ce_NPTfKFL=h310)
Multiple user pictures in the chat thumbnail, a bit similar to something that Facebook does.

If not fresco, is there something else that I should be using.

Answer (score 0):

This is already explained in the [Fresco documentation](http://frescolib.org/docs/writing-custom-views.html). Just follow the instructions there.